# How to link SPA (Vue) and API (.Net Core) to use Auth0

Tags: vue.js, .net-core, auth0

I'm try Auth0 service and I want to build an API where I will be able to give access to some date securely to a mobile app and a SPA.

I build the API following those steps : https://auth0.com/blog/securing-asp-dot-net-core-2-applications-with-jwts/

Then I use the SPA template auth0 offered.

The SPA is working but I don't know how to link it with the API. I don't see where the JWT is handle on the front to make a call to `api/books` with the bearer token.

Comment: We have a two-part series on developing Web Apps with ASP.NET Core 2.0 and React. I think this will provide you the information you need, as long as you have some familiarity with React as well as Vue. https://auth0.com/blog/developing-web-apps-with-asp-dot-net-core-2-dot-0-and-react-part-1/

Comment: Thank I will look at it but I think I solve my issue. I was looking at the `access_token` instead of the `id_token` and didn't put the `app_id` of my vue in the `audience` on the API. But my question now is, can I use the same API but for mutiple client ? Like one SPA, one mobile and API to api (what you call machine to machine I think ?)